# Opening and performing an operation on multiple files

Tags: python, file

I have 3 files that contain lists of other files in the directory. I'm trying take the files that are in the lists and copy them to a new directory. I think I'm tripping up on the best way to open the files as I get a IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I had a play around using with to open the files but couldn't get my operation to work. Here's my code and a bit of one of the files I'm trying to read.

```
import shutil
import os

f=open('polymorphI_hits.txt' 'polymorphII_hits.txt' 'polymorphIII_hits.txt')
res_files=[line.split()[1] for line in f]
f=close()

os.mkdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Clustered/polymorph_matches'))

for file in res_files:
    shutil.copy(file, (os.path.expanduser('~/Clustered/polymorph_matches')) + "/" + file)

PENCEN.res      2.res   number molecules matched:       15      rms deviation   0.906016
PENCEN.res      3.res   number molecules matched:       15      rms deviation   1.44163
PENCEN.res      5.res   number molecules matched:       15      rms deviation   0.867366
```

Edit: I used Ayas code below to fix this but now get IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'p'. I'm guessing its reading the first character of the file name and failing there but I can't figure out why.

```
res_files = []
for filename in 'polymorphI_hits.txt' 'polymorphII_hits.txt' 'polymorphIII_hits.txt':
    res_files += [line.split()[1] for line in open(filename)]
```

Comment: Copy/paste fail? Check the answer again, and you should notice commas separating the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Python treats consecutive string constants as a single string, so the line...

```
f=open('polymorphI_hits.txt' 'polymorphII_hits.txt' 'polymorphIII_hits.txt')
```

...is actually interpreted as...

```
f=open('polymorphI_hits.txtpolymorphII_hits.txtpolymorphIII_hits.txt')
```

...which presumably refers to a non-existent file.

I don't believe there's a way to use `open()` to open multiple files in one call, so you'll need to change...

```
f=open('polymorphI_hits.txt' 'polymorphII_hits.txt' 'polymorphIII_hits.txt')
res_files=[line.split()[1] for line in f]
f=close()
```

...to something more like...

```
res_files = []
for filename in 'polymorphI_hits.txt', 'polymorphII_hits.txt', 'polymorphIII_hits.txt':
    res_files += [line.split()[1] for line in open(filename)]
```

The rest of the code looks okay, though.

Comment: I see where I was going wrong thanks for the help! I still get: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'p' and I'm not sure where that's come from.